# Major Green Android Newbie looking for advice

Tags: android

I'm kind of a Jack of all Trades in the IT field, but have no programming experience.

Without having prior programing knowledge, will it be difficult to begin learning how to develop Android apps?  Basically, I'm looking for advice on a road map, for example, should I learn C+ or Java first before I begin anything Android?

Thanks.

Comment: there are hundred of tutorials on writing your first android app starting with the android documentation like the helloworld http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html .  If you have NO programming experience you will want to learn some programming language concepts first and you might as well do it in Java.

Answer (score 2):

You should start with java. Android uses java, and learning C++ would only help you learn java later on.

I'm guessing it would take you (though, remember it's very subjective) a few months to learn how to make your own apps. Start by learning basic java, and then move on to the android API (you shouldn't try to learn java by trying out android).

This is just my opinion though.

Comment: Thank you for that advice, I'm going to give it a shot.  And yes, I fully expect it to take some time to lay the ground work, but everyone has to start somewhere I guess.

Comment: Oh yeah, and did I say that right, should I be concerned with C+ or C++?  Yeah, I'm green all right. :)

Comment: I've been learning java since september (part time), and android since january. I have never used C++, and I've never felt like I'm missing out (from an android perspective). Technically, it's used to programme for hardware, but if you wanna develop apps, you'll be fine learning basic object-oriented programming concepts (by learning java).

Comment: Oh and, I'm very glad I studied basic java for a few months before I started with android.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'm going to give it a shot and see what I can accomplish.  Looking forward to it...

Comment: Np. You should. It's very fun :) And you get instant results ;)